Drag and Drop functionality is not working in selenium Webdriver?
I am trying to drag an element into another element using Selenium WebDriver but it's not working. I tried all the solutions which I can find on the internet but none of the solutions seems to be working for me.
I have two borrowers list Bor1, Bor2. I have to move the bor2 into the bor1 position like a shuffle. I tried selenium Actions class its not supporting.
I tried JavascriptExecutor. It runs without any error but drag and drop is not happening in the application. Does anyone have any other solution? Thanks.
I am using selenium.version - 3.141.59, Browser - Chrome.
here is my page source.
 Ken Customer  Patriots Dawson 
This is my code
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cdk-drag.active"));
        String sourcetext = source.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("Source text is Found : "+ sourcetext);
        WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cdk-drag:not(.active)"));
        String destinationtext = destination.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("Source text is Found : "+ destinationtext);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        
        final String java_script = 
                ("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
                + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
                + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
                + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
                + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
                + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
                + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
                + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
                + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
                + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
                + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
                + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
                + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
                + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
                + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
                + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);");
                
        //js.executeScript(java_script, borrower2Before, borrower1Before);
         Boolean borrowerPositionModifiedOkButtonBooleanEle = false;
           int i = 1;
            while(!borrowerPositionModifiedOkButtonBooleanEle && i<5) {
                i++;
            System.out.println("Tried Count  : "+i);
            try {
                js.executeScript(java_script, destination, source);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                     if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(getElementTargetID("1003BorrowerPositionModifiedOkButton"))).isDisplayed()) {
                    borrowerPositionModifiedOkButtonBooleanEle = true;       





                    break;
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                addExceptionToReport("Script failed", "", "");
            }
            
            }
        
        WebElement BorrowerPositionModifiedOkButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(getElementTargetID("1003BorrowerPositionModifiedOkButton")));
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(BorrowerPositionModifiedOkButton));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(getElementTargetID("1003BorrowerPositionModifiedOkButton"))).click();

